# Combine three queries' results and use them in one another query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to use these three queries:

First query:

```
SELECT 
    AMICOS.PNRREG.PN, Max(AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.HISTORYDATE) AS lastissue 
FROM 
    AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT 
INNER JOIN 
    AMICOS.PNRREG ON AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.PARTID = AMICOS.PNRREG.PARTID 
WHERE 
    (((AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.ACTION)='ISSUE') AND    
    ((AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.HISTORYDATE)<to_date('31032019','DDMMYYYY')+1)) 
GROUP BY 
    AMICOS.PNRREG.PN;
```

Second query:

```
SELECT 
    AMICOS.PNRREG.PN, Max(AMICOS.HISTORY.HISTORYDATE) AS lastissuehistory
FROM
    AMICOS.HISTORY 
INNER JOIN 
    AMICOS.PNRREG ON AMICOS.HISTORY.PARTID = AMICOS.PNRREG.PARTID
WHERE 
   (((AMICOS.HISTORY.HISTORYACTION)='ISSUE') AND 
    ((AMICOS.HISTORY.HISTORYDATE)<to_date('31032019','DDMMYYYY')+1))
GROUP BY 
    AMICOS.PNRREG.PN;
```

Third query:

```
SELECT 
    AMICOS.PNRREG.PN, Max(AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.HISTORYDATE) AS lastpurchase
FROM
    AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT 
INNER JOIN 
    AMICOS.PNRREG ON AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.PARTID = AMICOS.PNRREG.PARTID
WHERE 
    (((AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.HISTORYDATE)<to_date('31032019','DDMMYYYY')+1))
GROUP BY 
    AMICOS.PNRREG.PN, AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.ACTION
HAVING 
    (((AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.ACTION)='PURCHASE'));
```

And this last query which put those together:

```
SELECT AMICOS.PNRREG.PN, AMICOS.IRCABCCAT.ABC_CATEGORY, AMICOS.IRC.PRIMUTILISATION, AMICOS.PNRREG.DESCRIPTION, AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.ACCOUNTNO, AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.HISTORYDATE, AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.STOCK_FLOAT, AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.STOCK_PRICE, AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.STOCKVALUE, lastpurchase.lastpurchase, lastissue.lastissue, lastissuehistory.lastissuehistory
FROM ((AMICOS.PNRREG LEFT JOIN lastissuehistory ON AMICOS.PNRREG.PN = lastissuehistory.PN LEFT JOIN lastissue ON AMICOS.PNRREG.PN = lastissue.PN) 
LEFT JOIN lastpurchase ON AMICOS.PNRREG.PN = lastpurchase.PN);
```

I have tried UNION, JOIN to put those Queries together to get one result from this last queries which is dependending of those three other queries.

It works on MS Access when i have predefined queries of these first three queries. But it doesn't work on Oracle SQL Developer query tool.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a `CTE` (common table expression, i.e. the `WITH` factoring clause) might help. Something like this:

```
with 
  first  as (select pn, ... from ...),
  second as (select pn, ... from ...),
  third  as (select pn, ... from ...)
-- now, join them
select f.pn, s.some_column, t.some_other_column
from first f join second s on s.pn = f.pn
join third t on t.pn = f.pn
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the With or the following option

```
SELECT 
    AMICOS.PNRREG.PN, 
    AMICOS.IRCABCCAT.ABC_CATEGORY, 
    AMICOS.IRC.PRIMUTILISATION, 
    AMICOS.PNRREG.DESCRIPTION, 
    AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.ACCOUNTNO, 
    AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.HISTORYDATE, 
    AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.STOCK_FLOAT, 
    AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.STOCK_PRICE, 
    AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.STOCKVALUE, 
    lastpurchase.lastpurchase, 
    lastissue.lastissue, 
    lastissuehistory.lastissuehistory
FROM 
    AMICOS.PNRREG

LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
AMICOS.PNRREG.PN, 
Max(AMICOS.HISTORY.HISTORYDATE) AS lastissuehistory
FROM 
    AMICOS.HISTORY 
    INNER JOIN AMICOS.PNRREG ON AMICOS.HISTORY.PARTID = AMICOS.PNRREG.PARTID
WHERE (((AMICOS.HISTORY.HISTORYACTION)='ISSUE') AND ((AMICOS.HISTORY.HISTORYDATE)<to_date('31032019','DDMMYYYY')+1))
GROUP BY AMICOS.PNRREG.PN) lastissuehistory ON AMICOS.PNRREG.PN = lastissuehistory.PN 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
AMICOS.PNRREG.PN, 
Max(AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.HISTORYDATE) AS lastissue 
FROM 
    AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT 
    INNER JOIN AMICOS.PNRREG ON AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.PARTID = AMICOS.PNRREG.PARTID 
WHERE 
(((AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.ACTION)='ISSUE') AND ((AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.HISTORYDATE)<to_date('31032019','DDMMYYYY')+1)) 
GROUP BY AMICOS.PNRREG.PN)lastissue ON AMICOS.PNRREG.PN = lastissue.PN

LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
    AMICOS.PNRREG.PN, 
    Max(AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.HISTORYDATE) AS lastpurchase
FROM 
    AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT 
    INNER JOIN AMICOS.PNRREG ON AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.PARTID = AMICOS.PNRREG.PARTID
WHERE (((AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.HISTORYDATE)<to_date('31032019','DDMMYYYY')+1))
GROUP BY AMICOS.PNRREG.PN, AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.ACTION
HAVING (((AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.ACTION)='PURCHASE'))) lastpurchase ON AMICOS.PNRREG.PN = lastpurchase.PN
```

Comment: This comes with error, it can't find tables:
    AMICOS.PNRREG.PN, 
    AMICOS.IRCABCCAT.ABC_CATEGORY, 
    AMICOS.IRC.PRIMUTILISATION, 
    AMICOS.PNRREG.DESCRIPTION, 
    AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.ACCOUNTNO, 
    AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.HISTORYDATE, 
    AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.STOCK_FLOAT, 
    AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.STOCK_PRICE, 
    AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.STOCKVALUE

Somehow.. But i will try this with WITH.

Regards 

Erneeraq

Comment: Try to replace in thre three left join the field AMICOS.PNRREG.PN, do you have the PN field in the historystockfloat table ? if yes update it and update the group by too

Answer (score 0):

@Littlefoot
I tried something like this:

```
WITH
first as (SELECT AMICOS.PNRREG.PN, Max(AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.HISTORYDATE) AS lastissue FROM AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT INNER JOIN AMICOS.PNRREG ON                   AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.PARTID = AMICOS.PNRREG.PARTID WHERE (((AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.ACTION)='ISSUE') AND                                           ((AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.HISTORYDATE)<to_date('31032019','DDMMYYYY')+1)) GROUP BY AMICOS.PNRREG.PN),
second as (SELECT AMICOS.PNRREG.PN, Max(AMICOS.HISTORY.HISTORYDATE) AS lastissuehistory
       FROM AMICOS.HISTORY INNER JOIN AMICOS.PNRREG ON AMICOS.HISTORY.PARTID = AMICOS.PNRREG.PARTID
       WHERE (((AMICOS.HISTORY.HISTORYACTION)='ISSUE') AND ((AMICOS.HISTORY.HISTORYDATE)<to_date('31032019','DDMMYYYY')+1))
       GROUP BY AMICOS.PNRREG.PN),
third as (SELECT AMICOS.PNRREG.PN, Max(AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.HISTORYDATE) AS lastpurchase
FROM AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT INNER JOIN AMICOS.PNRREG ON AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.PARTID = AMICOS.PNRREG.PARTID
WHERE (((AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.HISTORYDATE)<to_date('31032019','DDMMYYYY')+1))
GROUP BY AMICOS.PNRREG.PN, AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.ACTION
HAVING (((AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.ACTION)='PURCHASE')))
SELECT AMICOS.PNRREG.PN, AMICOS.IRCABCCAT.ABC_CATEGORY, AMICOS.IRC.PRIMUTILISATION,
AMICOS.PNRREG.DESCRIPTION, AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.ACCOUNTNO,
AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.HISTORYDATE, AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.STOCK_FLOAT,
AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.STOCK_PRICE, AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.STOCKVALUE,
lastpurchase.lastpurchase, lastissue.lastissue, lastissuehistory.lastissuehistory
FROM ((AMICOS.PNRREG LEFT JOIN lastpurchase ON AMICOS.PNRREG.PN = lastpurchase.PN
LEFT JOIN lastissue ON AMICOS.PNRREG.PN = lastissue.PN) LEFT JOIN lastissuehistory ON
AMICOS.PNRREG.PN = lastissuehistory.PN;
```

But it  keeps telling me "Select list inconsistent with GROUP BY; amend GROUP BY clause to: AMICOS.PNRREG.PN, AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.ACTION, Max(AMICOS.HISTORYSTOCKFLOAT.HISTORYDATE)"

Regards
Erneeraq

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this work with the help of this guide: [Use lookupset function in SSRS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f30ff0d2-ba37-4bb8-b0a0-a6e06b3273fd/two-datasets-inside-a-same-tablix?forum=sqlreportingservices)

The one suggetion from Katherine Xiong.

Regards

Erneeraq